# Protect photo ownership using blockchain

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity

I am new to blockchain technology and i want to make a project on protecting photo ownership using blockchain. I have read many articles and research papers on this topic. And tried some udemy courses too.
Which blockchain technology shall i use?
how to store images in block of blockchain?
Can i take image as an input using solidity?

Comment: The choice of blockchain technology is an opionion question, so I'm not sure stackoverflow is the right place for that. Since you're not sure which blockchain protocol you want to use yet, handling images will then depend on the individual choice.

Answer (score 0):

Photo ownership can be protected using Blockchain Technology. You have to decide what are the parameters of photo ownership to be stored in Blockchain. Blockchain by design stores the time stamp of the photo ownership. Blockchain also provides a tamper evident audit trail. You can decide what all activities related to Photo ownership need to be stored in Blockchain. You have to map the lifecycle of photo file creation, edit, update activities into Blockchain. It is also important to map all the users involved in the creation, edit and update of the photo as the participants in the photo ownership network. If you are planning to use Ethereum Blockchain protocol, you can write the smart contracts for photo ownership in Solidity language. You can store the image in IPFS and pass the hash of the image into the Solidity Smart Contract. You can also store the image in other distributed file systems and databases such as MongoDB, OrbitDB, FlureeDB, BigChainDB etc. Please find a reference Dapp for this use case [here](https://github.com/iwaldman/ipfs-image-dapp).